# Best "store locator" - "map" jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery

can someone suggest me the best "store locator" tool (better if it is jQuery)?
I need to organize more than 100 points on the map.
thank you

Answer (score 7):

I think this is what you were looking for (I was too!-): https://github.com/bjorn2404/jQuery-Store-Locator-Plugin

Answer (score 1):

You could try 
[www.traveltimeapp.com](http://www.traveltimeapp.com)
api: [igeolise.3scale.net](http://igeolise.3scale.net)

You can list stores then by how far the user is in time, not distance... way more useful!

Answer (score 1):

we just launched one, and it has all of the functionality of a store locator (bulk upload of locations from spreadsheet, sorting via dropdown tags, zip//city search by geolocation, custom pinpoints and so on). It also allows custom images for maps. Here's the link: http://www.mapifypro.com

Answer (score 1):

We evaluated a number of the locator scripts in the marketplace but quickly realized how much effort would be required in setting up the location management system, making it highly available / resilient, mobile responsive and cross compatible with all the major browsers etc. What seems like a simple requirement on face value is fairly painful when you dig into all the development time that is needed.

In the end, after reviewing a number of commercial services we settled on Store Locator Pro / http://www.storelocatorwidgets.com mostly due to the excellent customer support they provided. (answering the original question, it is a JQuery based store locator).

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this JQuery widget that can be used to place your store locations on a Google Map.

http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/locator

This PHP article may help as well:

http://wiki.modxcms.com/index.php/Store_Locator

Finally try out this article as well:

[Google Maps: Store locator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915938/google-maps-store-locator)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to worry about setting up your own database for locations, creating proximity queries, worrying about creating interface for location management, etc. give this API a go, provides easy to use location management interface and an API for your proximity calls. http://www.ehoundplatform.com/proximity-api

Answer (score 0):

Google's Store locator example for Google Maps API v3:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3.html

Answer (score 0):

http://weblogs.asp.net/ruslan/archive/2012/04/17/complete-jquery-store-locator-with-google-maps-api-google-distance-matrix-api-html5-geolocation-amp-google-maps-kml-file-as-data-source.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have created multiple sites including Wordpress, Joomla!, Squarespace, Drupal as well as static HTML websites using http://superstorefinder.net . It takes a few steps to install and you can use the embed code like YouTube and paste it at your website or page editor.

The frontend has Geo location, street view, directions and distance calculation to show from nearest to furthest available stores. From the admin backend, you can manage your stores via admin and it also has import bulk address using CSV feature.