# Outline sales territory on Google Maps using V3 API and a list of Zip Codes

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to create a tool that would take a list of zip codes as the input and would output a google map using the V3 of their API. The area on the map that corresponds to these zip codes needs to be outlined/color.

So far, I can draw shapes and distance circles, but have been unable to add zip coverage. A pointer to a tutorial or some sample code would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: I don't live in the US, but is this table helpful for you? https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/ZIP_code_prefixes

Comment: ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814169/geographical-boundaries-of-states-provinces-google-maps-polygon

Comment: Here's a useful bit of information about where you can get the ZIP boundary information and how to make sense of the files that contain it: [ZIP Code Database from Census Data](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/10/zip_code_database_created_from.html)

Comment: @ timdream, thank you. The overlay is essentially the same function I'm looking for, but I'm trying to avoid using actual images or similar static things to represent the boundaries, as sales territories change fairly regularly - zips are added and removed very few months.

Comment: @lthibodeaux, that is exactly what I'm trying to do! That said, I was hoping there is a more out of the box solution.

Comment: @Sologoub Yeah you're going to have to get your hands dirty with coding the overlays yourself I'm afraid. Don't know what you're using to render your page but I'm about to embark on a similar project and I'll be loading the poly's vertices asynchronously through a page method in ASP.NET and jQuery's $.ajax().

Comment: yeah, I was afraid of that - the app's out put is a visualforce page in salesforce.com, so I was hoping to keep it very light and leverage existing libraries/APIs as much as possible. Thank you!