# Geolocation (lat/long) to US state in java

Tags: java, geolocation, latitude-longitude, geofencing

I've never worked with geolocation data heavily  before, but I've just run into the need to rapidly analyze a large result set's latitude and longitude data and essentially geofence a subset of the data to particular states.

What I'm looking for is a local library or API that can process raw lat and long data and spit out the corresponding US state of that value for comparison pretty quickly. I'm looking to analyze 1mm sets fairly rapidly, and the data cannot be uploaded to a foreign server for analysis. In my brief nosing around I've found some solutions that work with zip codes, is there an existing solution out there or am I going to have to rely on rough lat long qualifiers?

Comment: Take a look at Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874686/google-maps-v3-draw-german-state-polygons/14336434#14336434).

You can solve your problem by using some database or the Google GeoChart API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Java, but if it has any spatial functionality, you can get state map boundaries at the U.S. government's site NationalAtlas (dot) gov and use something like the SQL Server STIntersects method to determine what state a set of coordinates falls within.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the ESRI geodata toolsets in the past. Remember doing something like this. Please take a look here, if it helps:

http://www.esri.com/apps/products/download/#ArcGIS_Extensions