# Google map customization - clickable country/state

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Just started my research in google map API and worked out some basic examples(lat-lng, geocode, dynamic markers,..), now i need your help for the next level. Here is my scenario, in a particular country, all the states to be clickable as markers. Say Example in Australia, events should be fired if i click anywhere in Western Australia state and same for other states.

For your better understanding, here is the reference [**link**](http://www.realestate.com.au/buy)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps V3: Draw German State Polygons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874686/google-maps-v3-draw-german-state-polygons) [Australia](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_query_sidebarF_local.html?country=Australia)

Answer (score 0):

Your example, I don't think it's using google maps api. It just has some images of the states that are listening for the click event to load the suburbs. What you are asking though is this scenario:

1. Load the map and center on a certain position, zoom etc.
2. Listen to the map for the click event

   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event){
      alert('Lat: ' + event.latLng.lat() + ' and Longitude is: ' + event.latLng.lng());
   });

Now you have the point clicked so you can show whatever info you want

Comment: What i linked for reference might be image, but can we do like that using map for country wise?

Comment: I think you could do it with google charts, resolution provinces.

Comment: Thanks. finally i end up with jQuery ImageMapster . This is what i expected. ==> http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_usa.html

Comment: You should post your comment as an answer and accept it. It's pretty valuable information and it would be more useful as an answer rather than a comment that can easily be missed.