# Highlight boundaries of ZIP-code areas in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, highlight, zipcode

I'd like to highlight certain areas on google maps by giving it an ZIP-code. So far I've found solutions for highlighting separate countries and regions ([Google Maps V3: Draw German State Polygons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874686/google-maps-v3-draw-german-state-polygons)) inside them but I'd need something more detailed. Is it achievable using google maps API or do I need my own database with coordinates for each ZIP-code area?
One more thing - I'd like to have this area highlight of ZIP-codes for Europe, Denmark specifically. I've seen some good solutions for US, though none for Europe.

Thanks