# How to get the JSON file

Tags: json, google-maps, dictionary

How can I get the list (json) of markers at the map from this web site http://espace-sfr.sfr.fr/espace-sfr/recherche

I need to get the markers from map to display them at my own map. So if there is any json file with all that points and coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the google maps api

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/

You can query for a certain location and you will receive json coordinates.

Comment: but where are stored this coordinates?

Comment: from which location do you want the coordinates ? http://www.gps-coordinates.net/

Comment: this is what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874686/google-maps-v3-draw-german-state-polygons

Comment: sorry, but u didnt understand. I want to get markers lattitude an longtitude  that are already displayed at http://espace-sfr.sfr.fr/espace-sfr/recherche

Comment: well unless espace-sfr has a dataset with the coordinates. I don't believe you can retrieve them from the displayed map

Answer (score 0):

supposed you have jsonfile

```
                for (var i = 0; i < jsonfile.length; i++) {


               var pos=   new google.maps.LatLng(jsonfile[i].lat,jsonfile[i].lng);


            }
```