# Google MAP region co ordinates and polygons

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to create an Angular application that relies heavily on google maps. I would like to highlight areas on the map by continent->country->state->suburb and depending on the values of supplied will determine what the highlighted areas coluor would be.

I have read that with google map polygons you need to set the boundary co ordinates so that the polygon will display/cover in he correct places. The first part of this question is if this is true where would I begin to get all the co ordinates for these boundaries? is it already built into google and I missed it?

Second part of the question is am I approaching this problem the right way is there a better solution to this. I have inserted an example image below of what I am looking to recreate dynamically.

Any guidance on this will be appreciated.[example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sApl.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have all the coordinates of the polygon, and I'm afraid you'll have to retrieve them by yourself somehow. Although it might be possible that somebody else has already made a list of coordinates that represent a certain country/state/etc but still you would need to find them first (and use them with the Google Maps API).

Maybe you could make a small tool with Google Maps API, that will let you click the polygon coordinates to the map and then give you back the list of the coordinates?

Comment: I thought about your second option and its just too much for one dev to do. I am searching for locations on the web where I can find all the co ordinates. A plus would be if they are in JSON

Comment: It seems that somebody has actually collected a database of countries, and atleast some of them have the coordinates already in the json format. Check out this older answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10875909/5526468

Comment: thanks I will look at this LOADS of data to sift through but that is a good start thank you.