# Need country state borders geofences from google map or xml file

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-earth, google-geocoder, states

Here i want india state border geofences. 
is there any way to download state borders from google map ?

Or is there any possible solution to generate it from google earth with kmz/kml format.

like, [state border image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wj3dZ.png)

Is there any possible way to get this state borders coordinates with google map api also ?

please help me out, it will save lots of time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps V3: Draw German State Polygons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874686/google-maps-v3-draw-german-state-polygons)

Comment: That's the perfect solution, **Thanks man**, it will help a lot...!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't get state borders from google map api, there isn't this choice, but you can download it in kmz type of file from here:
http://www.gadm.org/download

Comment: Thanks for answering...!! It will help a bit.