# Google Maps: how to find map boundaries?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a function in Google Maps API that will return an array of lat/lng values defining a polygon for a given location? For example:

- USA
- Nevada
- Las Vegas

If not available in Google Maps API, is there some online source I can get this info from?

Comment: Are you looking for an exact polygon with the political borders or just a rectangular bounding box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the bounding box then you can use the geocoding service, for example

- [Nevada](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=nevada)
- [Las Vegas](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=Las%20Vegas)
- [USA](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=usa)

and read **results[0].geometry.bounds.northeast** and **results[0].geometry.bounds.southwest**

On the other hand, if you want exact political borders you need to download and process shapefiles from somewhere, like [**Natural Earth Data**](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/) or the [**US Census Bureau**](http://www.census.gov/geo/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends if you want the bounds of a pre-defined polygon or if you are making your own polygon for the state of Nevada for example.  If you are doing you own then you can use build in functions to get the lat/longs.  If you are looking for predefined ones then you will need to dig them up as they don't exist in v3 to my knowledge.

This nice guy has provided the states in XML format if that helps?

[US States Graphical Boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814169/geographical-boundaries-of-states-provinces-google-maps-polygon)

If you are looking to get the bounds of an existing polygon, then here is a method that works in V3:

[Get the bounds of a polygon in Google Maps V3](http://blog.dyve.net/the-boundaries-of-a-polygon-in-google-maps-ap)